# Is there a scikit-learn/keras function for non-linear regression?

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression

i'm trying to **predict** some parameters based on others, data is 24 inputs and 1 output (for 595 day).

I already tried to create a neural network with **10-fold cross validation** but it gives me error between 30% and 15% in training and 40% in testing.

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    # Adding the input layer
    model.add(Dense(24, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', input_shape=(24,)))
    # Adding the hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(50, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    # Compiling the RNN
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_percentage_error')

    return model

kf = KFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True)
Density = create_model()
```

Don't know how could I **minimize the error** ? Or there's a **function for regression** ?

Comment: What is the range of values at the output? Your last layer has no activation function, you probably want to change that. Also, how did you come up with the model architecture?

Comment: the range of values at the output is between 6 and 59,5. and for the architecture I just tried it (actually I studie mechanical engineering so it my first time with neural networks...).

Comment: I will be very grateful if you have any advice.

Comment: @SB_help08 could you post some example data.

Comment: @SB_help08 Reading the comments from the code, it is not RNN to my knowledge. It is a feed forward neural network.